# I need help centering my table and wrap my text

Tags: columns, code, text, wrap

I hope you could help me with my noob question.

I have this code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{\label{tab:vantagens}bus network}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tabular}{ |c|m{7cm}| }
 \hline
 Vantagens & Desvantagens \\ 
 \hline 
 Rede mais simples & Difícil correcção e detecção de erros \\ 
 \hline 
 Implementação mais barata & Uma quebra no cabo pode comprometer o acesso dos dispositivos à rede \\ 
 \hline
 Não são necessários equipamento complexos & Problemático ao adicionar e remover dispositivos da rede  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

[image]

I would like to center my right column and just wrap the text.

I will make some tables with a 2 lines of text each lines.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
\caption{\label{tab:vantagens}bus network}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tabular}{ |c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}| } % <---
 \hline
 Vantagens & Desvantagens \\
 \hline
 Rede mais simples & Difícil correcção e detecção de erros \\
 \hline
 Implementação mais barata & Uma quebra no cabo pode comprometer o acesso dos dispositivos à rede \\
 \hline
 Não são necessários equipamento complexos & Problemático ao adicionar e remover dispositivos da rede  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- Float had not be inside any fixes environment as it is `center`. Instead it you should use `\centering` inside floats as is done in above MWE (Minimum Working Example).
- Please in question always provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

[image]

However, your table is quite vide and it can happen that will spill of from right text border. Also space between caption and table is big. I would delete `\vskip 1cm` after `caption` and consider the table environment, to which I can prescribe width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % <---
\caption{\label{tab:vantagens}bus network}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X | } % <---
 \hline
 Vantagens & Desvantagens \\
 \hline
 Rede mais simples & Difícil correcção e detecção de erros \\
 \hline
 Implementação mais barata & Uma quebra no cabo pode comprometer o acesso dos dispositivos à rede \\
 \hline
 Não são necessários equipamento complexos & Problemático ao adicionar e remover dispositivos da rede  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nice result (to my test) you will obtain if the both column will have  equal type:

```
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X |} } % <---
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `nicematrix` package

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{Y{0.5}Y{0.5}}
\toprule[2pt]
    Vantagens & Desvantagens \\ 
    \midrule 
    Rede mais simples & Difícil correcção e detecção de erros \\ 
    \midrule
    Implementação mais barata & Uma quebra no cabo pode comprometer o acesso dos dispositivos à rede \\ 
    \midrule
    Não são necessários equipamento complexos & Problemático ao adicionar e remover dispositivos da rede  \\ 
    \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The percentage of text width to be occupied can be changed easily

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{Y{0.4}Y{0.6}}
```

instead of

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{Y{0.5}Y{0.5}}
```

to give the following result

[image]